# .htaccess and VirtualHost not working

Tags: 14.04, apache2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I'm having trouble getting my .htaccess to work with the Laravel PHP framework on Rackspace Cloud Server/Ubuntu 14/Apache 2.

Mod_rewrite is enabled using sudo a2enmod rewrite. I've reset and restarted Apache.

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

<Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
  Options -Indexes
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using the standard .htaccess setting recommended for Laravel; the same virtual host configuration and .htaccess work on a different Ubuntu 14/Apache 2 on my Rackspace account. (The only difference is the domain names.)

/var/www/example.com/public_html/.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: When I go to a URL that should be redirected to the Laravel front controller I get a standard 404 error instead.